# PS4 games not loading faster via SSD

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, hardware

I have a PS4 Slim and just got a Samsung Portable SSD T7 (1TB) drive. The drive has 1050MB/s read & 1000MB/s write speed via USB 3.2 Gen2. I hooked it up to my PS4 and transferred a game onto it hoping for faster loading times. However, the game loads just as slowly as without the SSD. I’m playing locally, not over a network. Does anyone have an idea why games aren't loading faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While DialFrost's answer may be correct, the real trouble lies in the fact that it is an **external** SSD. The device itself may be as fast as ever, but things are still restricted by the cable that connects the PS4 to the drive.

The PS4 Slim only has USB 3.0/3.1 ports, so no matter what the Samsung device has, the PS4 Slim can only go as fast as 3.0/3.1 allows. Operations are happening quickly on the SSD itself, but the console cannot take advantage of this, as the storage is external to the device, and is restricted by the data flow of the cable that connects them.

SSD storage is becoming cheaper and cheaper. It may benefit you to follow a guide or [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLBJgmoDp7I) on replacing the internal PS4 Slim drive with an SSD. I did the same for my launch PS4 console, and enjoyed a much better experience with the console.

Answer (score 0):

The Ps4 Slim uses disc, and using a SSD will not boost your loading time much.

> Using a SSD in a PS4 Pro will reduce load times of games installed on the hard drive by about 20%. Games that are run from a disc only benefit about 3% - 5%. [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-SSD-for-PS4-Pro-boost-performance-or-just-the-load-times)

As you can see, you only benefit a mere 3 to 5%, which is quite unoticeable.

Comment: Thank you, but the game I'm playing is downloaded from the Playstation Store, and does not rely on disc.